# In html 5, how to positioning a div element on top of a canvas element?

Tags: css, html

Can anyone help me: I'm trying to put a div (say, 10px by 10px) element on top (in front) of a canvas element (say 500px by 500px) in html. I have tried changing the z-index of each, to no avail. Does anybody have any ideas, or is it one of those things that you can't really do? I already know how to do absolute positioning and everything, the div element just hangs out in the background behind the canvas element. I need a way to bring it to the front and the canvas element to the back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The way absolute positioning works is that, in general, elements that are earlier in the code are behind elements that are later in the code.  To change that you do indeed use z-index.  Note, though, that z-index only works on elements that are positioned.

Another thing that may be tripping you up is that *all* positioned elements act like z-index "containers".  So if your `<div>` happens to be earlier in the document and in another positioned container, it may be bound to the z-index layer of its ancestor, and so can't ever escape and display on top of the `<canvas>`.  If this is the case, you'll either have to slightly rewrite your CSS or rearrange your page so that the `<div>` is in a good spot.

Comment: Same issue as the OP: "Note, though, that z-index only works on elements that are positioned." was all I needed. Thanks @Xanthir

Answer (score 2):

That depends on where your elements are.

To use z-index you must set the position to either relative or absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have the same problem. I created a sample canvas / div like you're talking about here at JSbin: http://jsbin.com/adowo/edit

Is that what you're looking for? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could be a browser issue? It might help if the OP specified what they're using...

Comment: I tried in Firefox and Chrome... I don't think IE supports canvas so I don't think they're trying that, but yeah, more info would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this may occur in my experiences.
I don't know what is happening in the html5 canvas API.
If you want draw some figure under the div element, use `img` tag instead, listed bellow.

--- this sample code is written with prototype.js(1.6) ---

<-javascript-code->

```
var canvas = $('canvas');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, - 360 * Math.PI / 180, true);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(204, 204, 255, 1)';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 51, 153, 1)';
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
var imgStr = canvas.toDataURL();
var element = new Element('img', {'src' : imgStr);
var target = $('layer1');
target.insert(element);
```

<- html ->

```
<div id='layer2' style='z-index : 50;'>&nbsp;</div> 
<canvas id='canvas' style='z-index : 30;'></canvas>
<div id='layer1' style='z-index : 10;'></div>
```

By the way, my home page is written in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I futzed with this for a little while and finally got it to work after setting z-index of the thing I want in the background to -1 (versus some positive number).

Answer (score -7):

XHTML

```
<div id="canvas">
   <div id="topelement">
   </div>
</div>
```

Css Styling

```
#canvas { height: 500px; width: 500px; overflow: hidden; }
#topelement { height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; }
```

Comment: You completely misunderstand the question, which is about `<canvas>`, not something with an id of "canvas".